# In Highstock charts, Drill down not correctly showing when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im using highstock chart API to create bar chart which has a horizontal bar chart. The problem I'm having is that, when I scroll and click on a bar, drilldown doesn't come. Here is a example. 
  In there when I scrolled to the end and click on "Opera" this issue arise.

Here is the link : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrj2E/)

```
Please help me.
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: you forgot to link , or post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem with extremes on xAxis - after setting drilldown, you have less categories than before drilldown. Solution is to call `setExtremes()` after setting a chart, see: http://jsfiddle.net/zrj2E/2/

```
    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 1, false); //reset extremes
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'white'
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }
```